# Error giving during compilation in release mode

Tags: android, android-build

I am novice to andriod and I want to submit my first app to market. I following the steps as giving on developer site.When i try to build my application in release mode on command line it gives me following error.

code on command line

C:\Users\pavan.more\workspace\Litofinter>ant release

error---->
C:\Users\pavan.more\workspace\Litofinter>ant release
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Can anyone has idea?Why is it so??

Comment: What's the code that generates this error?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I edited my question, please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

I got that error because i have not installed Apache ant java library, which is a Java library and command-line tool whose mission is to drive processes described in build files as targets and extension points dependent upon each other. The main known usage of Ant is the build of Java applications. Ant supplies a number of built-in tasks allowing to compile, assemble, test and run Java applications.
 It is required for building application in release mode. For downloading Apache link is http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi   for installation use the link http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/apache/ant/tutorial_install_ant/index.htm.
Then from command line ant release will work for me.